# Azure server disk capacity filling up automatically at /var/opt/microsoft/mdtap/signatures.noindex what is causing this?

Tags: azure, docker, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu 20.4 instance running on Azure. It has docker & docker-compose installed on it.
It was running fine for the past two years, but all of a sudden the disk space hit 100% capacity.

The folder /var/opt/microsoft/mdtap/signatures.noindex keeps generating signatures that are 200+mb each every so often, and I have no idea why this is happening. I have to delete the folder every so often just so my server doesn't crash.

What is /var/opt/microsoft/mdtap/signatures.noindex and how do I stop Azure (perhaps Docker?) from filling it up?

Comment: Try this command - `mdatp config real-time-protection --value disabled
` and check other options here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/linux-support-perf?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Is this command safe? I don't know if I should disable the defender entirely

Comment: Should depend upon your corporate policies. If its a test environment definitely you may.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the criticality of our business we can either disable or uninstall Microsoft Defender ATP.

Else we can increase the storage capacity

For Manual Uninstallation:

```
sudo yum remove mdatp for RHEL and variants(CentOS and Oracle Linux).
sudo apt-get purge mdatp for Ubuntu and Debian systems.
```

Or we can turn on/off real time protection:

```
mdatp config real-time-protection --value [enabled|disabled]
```

For more information refer to [MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/linux-resources?view=o365-worldwide)